# How to specify owner and permissions for an NFS mount?

Tags: permissions, mount, nfs, group, fstab

I have an NFS mount in fstab:

```
10.0.12.10:/share1    /net/share1    nfs    rw    0    0
```

which defaults to root as owner and group and 777 permissions. How do I specify another owner and different permissions? I can use chown and chmod, but it certainly should be possible straight from the mount command?

The system OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible from the mount command, because mount has to handle a variety of different filesystem types - including ones that might not support 'classic' `ugo` unix style permissions.

You are "stuck with" `chown`/`chgrp`/`chmod`.  (Where applicable).

Bear in mind the server has permissions on its own filesystem.  It may well be doing some manner of mapping - more commonly you'll see `root` -> `nobody`, but NFSv4 and idmap opens a whole new can of worms there. (It doesn't apply direct uid/gid ownership, but rather maps userids against a common directory.)